# Session variable resets on refresh

Tags: php

I have a session variable 'touser' which resets everytime I refresh the page but my session variable for the whole session "user" does not reset.

```
<?php 
session_start(); require("source/header.php");
require("scripts/connection/signup/db.php");
?>

<?php 
session_start();
$touser=$_POST["chats"];
$_SESSION["touser"]=$touser;
echo $_SESSION["touser"];
?>
```

Comment: And question is...? Sorry, it's really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I don't want my 'touser' variable to reset after I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on page refresh POST values are gone and since you assign them to `$touser` and it used for session so every page refresh Session value is reset.

Solution is :-

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['touser'])) { // check if POST have that index or not
    $touser = $_POST["chats"]; // if yes then reassign it's value
    $_SESSION["touser"] = $touser;  // set reassigned value to session variable

}
 echo $_SESSION["touser"];// print session value (here if POST have data then new value will show otherwise old one will show)
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check, if `$_POST['touser']` exists.

```
<?php 

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['touser'])) {
    $touser = $_POST["chats"];
    $_SESSION["touser"] = $touser; 
}

echo $_SESSION["touser"];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check whether $_POST["chats"] is set or not and then put value into session.

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST["chats"])) {
    $_SESSION["touser"]=$_POST["chats"];
}

echo $_SESSION["touser"];
```