# PHP session data removed by java refresh

Tags: javascript, php, session, session-variables, page-refresh

Thank in advanced,

I was looking at creating a linked dropdown menu and found tutorial/code online

I have used this code twice to create lmsdropdown.php and clubdropdown.php. I am able to store the values from the lmsdropdown form is a session and echo them to clubdropdown (just for verification that values are present).

lmsdropdown is a php include within members.php and clubdropdown is an include in members2.php.

When I select a value on clubdropdown the page refreshes to populate the 2nd dropdown box and this results in my session data being cleared.

I am new to PHP/Javascript so the answer may be very obvious but this has had me stumped for a few days now. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Below is a merge of two snippets members2.php, that has taken the output of lmsdropdown and stored output in sessions. 
clubdropdown shows the java code and also the echo session statements

I am able to correctly echo the session data however the javascript seems to remove this when building dropdown 2.

```html
members.php session data

<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['lms'] = $_POST['lms'];
    $_SESSION['week'] =  $_POST['week'];

    if (!isset($_SESSION['usr_lvl']) or ($_SESSION['usr_lvl'] != 0)) {  
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    }

?>

clubdropdown output of session data

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    function reload(form) {
        var val = form.lge.options[form.lge.options.selectedIndex].value;
        self.location = 'members-page2.php?lge=' + val;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $usr = $_SESSION['usr_id'];
        @$lge=$_GET['lge']; // Use this line or below line if register_global is off
        if(strlen($lge) > 0 and !is_numeric($lge)){ // to check if $lge is numeric data or not. 
            echo "Data Error";
            exit;
        }
        $usr = $_SESSION['usr_id'];
        $lms=$_SESSION['lms'];
        $week=$_SESSION['week'];
        echo "<br>Value of \$week = $week<br>Value of \$lms = $lms <br>Value of \$usr = $usr";
```

The image below shows the session variables outputted to clubdropdown that is included in members2.php
[clubdropdown with variables shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEKRP.png)

This image shows the errors after a selection is made from th 1st dropdown.
[Error after list refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpP23.png)

From some of the answers to similar questions on here I assume the error is because the post data is being overwritten/removed on refresh but I thought that's what the session was for?

Any input is greatly received thank you.

Comment: * java**script** refresh

Comment: The tutorial for the drop downs can be viewed here. I used the 1st option drop_down.zip  http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_drop_down-download.php?download_style=1

Comment: Hi Don,

This might be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396944/session-variable-resets-on-refresh .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the values from `$_POST`, which the second time you run the page is absent. You need to add an `If(isset($_POST['lms'])){ $_SESSION['lms'] = $_POST['lms']; }` so that it is skipped if the `$_POST` value isn't present.

Currently, your `$_SESSION` variables are still there, but are being replaced with empty `$_POST` values.

I suspect you might be better off using an AJAX call to populate your dropdown list.

Comment: That is phenomenal Stuart, very much appreciated works a treat!

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck with your coding.